# How to generate PDF file from an HTML file using Reportlab and Pisa in Python?

Tags: python, html, pdf, reportlab, pisa

Have the following code setup as follows to generate a PDF document using Reportlab and Pisa in Python.

```
import cStringIO
import ho.pisa as pisa

def html_to_pdf(data, filename, open=False):
    pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
        cStringIO.StringIO(data),
        file(filename, "wb"))
```

My HTML file contains standard HTML content.

It's fully qualified path along with .html extension is assigned to the output_file variable.

Call it like this:

```
with open(output_file, "r") as my_file:
        contents = my_file.read()

html_to_pdf(contents, dest_pdf_file, open=True)
```

Get this error:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "sx.pisa3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devuser/myapp/app.py", line 8, in <module>
    from utils.fileutils import FileUtil
  File "/home/devuser/myapp/utils/fileutils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ho.pisa as pisa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/ho/pisa/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from sx.pisa3.pisa import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pisa import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/pisa.py", line 32, in <module>
    from pisa_document import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/pisa_document.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pisa_context import pisaContext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/pisa_context.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pisa_util import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pisa-3.0.33-py2.7.egg/sx/pisa3/pisa_util.py", line 55, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!")
ImportError: Reportlab Version 2.1+ is needed!
```

This is a "partial list" of what pip freeze yields.

```
Pillow==2.3.0
PyPDF2==1.25.1
html5lib==0.999
oneconf==0.3.7.14.04.1
pdfkit==0.5.0
pisa==3.0.33
reportlab==3.0
```

Seems like a broken installation issue...

Does anyone know how to fix this or any alternative methods (approaches and / or different libraries) used to generate HTML files into PDFs?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working... Uninstalled and reinstalled pisa and it worked! :)

```
sudo easy_install pisa
```

My code:

```
import cStringIO
import ho.pisa as pisa

class FileUtil:
    @staticmethod
    def html_to_pdf(html, output_file):
        pdfFile = file(output_file, "wb")
        pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
            cStringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), pdfFile)
        pdfFile.close()
```